# Windows 8 Custom Message Dialog without XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I want to create a custom MessageDialog which in terms of its interface is exactly the same as the provided MessageDialog except for one thing; The Content property acts like that of a ContentControl so I can place custom UI elements in it.

Though I cannot for the life of me figure out how the developers were able to create a class that could be 'shown' in the UI without specifying that it inherits from any sort of control in the framework.

How is it possible to create a regular class and specify its 'Template' in code?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by creating a Popup, set it's Child. and then open it. You can create any XAML controls in code, so this is not an issue.

```
Popup popup = new Popup { Child = CreateXamlControlInCode() };
popup.IsOpen = true;
```

For step by step instructions, see [this blog post](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2012/11/12/Creating-a-custom-async-dialog-for-your-Win8-apps-Part-2-CustomDialog.aspx).